# Usage of the noun 'news'

Tags: nouns, semantics, countable-nouns

I would like to ask you a question concerning the noun 'news'. I am aware that as an uncountable noun,  it is, thus, not possible to use the indefinite article preceding it. I am a bit unsure, however, if I can form a question using this noun in the following way: "Why is this news?" I have never heard anyone using it this way. When would you use this expression? I would use it to express that I can not grasp why some piece of news is occupying space in the media, but I've never heard anyone using it in a similar context. I am a non-native speakers, so I frequently have doubts. :)

Comment: [Why is this news](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22why+is+this+news%22+&btnG=Search+Books&bksoutput=html_text&tbm=bks&tbo=1)?

Comment: "Why is this news?" is a very common usage.

Answer (score 3):

The expression is fairly common. I have heard it used as you are using it, to point out that something in the news is not interesting or new. It is also used to say something along the lines of "no one is surprised by that" or "why are you telling me something so obvious?".

Answer (score -2):

This is an idiomatic usage of the word 'new.' You can use the definitive article with news, as in, 'the news of the day.'

'Why is this news?' is a question being asked daily by thousands of news editors and the like across the land to hapless reporters. Whether that makes it grammatically correct is a question I leave to your own best judgment.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you can argue that it's an idiomatic use of "new".  Certainly by now "news" is a full-fledged word in its own right.

Comment: I believe its origin is idiomatic. I was trying to explain why a noun formed from an adjective would not follow the rule of use of definite article.